# apt-get update reports 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: apt

I recently noticed that `apt-get update` and `aptitude update` report some errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/debian/dists/wheezy/main/binary-amd64/Packages: Bad header line
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/dists/stable/contrib/binary-amd64/Packages: 406  Not Acceptable
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages: 406  Not Acceptable
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/dists/stable/contrib/binary-i386/Packages: 406  Not Acceptable
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/dists/stable/non-free/binary-i386/Packages: 406  Not Acceptable
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
E: Couldn't rebuild package cache
```

I looked at the server and found out that only `Packages.gz` and `Packages.bz2`, but not `Packages` exist. This also happens on the main server, not only on `ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de`.

After some research I found out that all mirors recently updated to only contain the `Packages` file in an compressed format but no longer plain. How can I tell `apt-get` and/or `aptitude` to use the compressed files instead the plain ones?

This is my `sources.list` (I've edited it, but it worked before):

```bash
#deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main
deb http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/ stable main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stable/updates main contrib

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
#deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib
#deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib
deb http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/ stable-updates main contrib

deb http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ubuntuzilla/mozilla/apt all main

#deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/ wheezy-backports main contrib non-free

#deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
```

In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` are the following files:

- `apt-build.list`

  ```bash
  # deb file:/var/cache/apt-build/repository/ apt-build main
  ```
- `dropbox.list`

  ```bash
  deb [arch=i386,amd64] http://linux.dropbox.com/debian wheezy main
  ```
- `google-chrome.list`

  ```bash
  ###
  ### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
  # You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
  deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  ```

Comment: Can you post your sources.list in the question, please? Also check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for additional sources.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I added the files you requested, can you help me now?

Comment: Sorry, I could not reproduce your issue with those urls. You wrote "only Packages.gz and Packages.bz2, but not Packages exist." what server are you referring to? Can you show a url where `Packages` does not exist? In any case, if the problem persists, I suggest first try removing `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/` and if that doesn't work, switch servers.

Comment: @FaheemMitha http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/ and ftp://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/ both don't contain `Packages` (at least when I visit them using my browser)

Comment: You're right,they don't. I'm not sure if that is a problem, though. I'm not seeing any errors here.

Comment: Use `wget http://ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/debian/dists/stable/non-free/binary-i386/Packages` from the system you are having problem with. IMO it should be the repository fault (as they normally just use a webserver to serve the files).

Comment: `apt-get` in Debian wheezy can deal with `Packages.gz` or `Packages.bz2` just fine. Your problem looks like a broken proxy. What are your proxy settings? Can you connect to the web directly? Maybe try an FTP or HTTPS mirror instead if you're stuck with this broken proxy.

Comment: @Gilles No, I don't have a proxy, and writing ftp instead of http doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

[Other bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/940825) & [here](http://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=5093.0) say to switch to a different mirror, update, then switch back. Could be caused from the server not supporting partial downloads correctly?

- Delete partially downloaded files in `/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/` should work, then try an update again.

Apparently some change to apt or dpkg, hopefully fixed with a newer upstream version.

Otherwise, it sounds like you might be using an old version (or buggy version) of `apt` that can't handle the compressed files. Is your system very old or not updated in a long time? There may be an updated version of `apt` you could try by manually browsing your repos (`stable` or `stable-updates` would be best, sticking to whatever is default/supported for your distro should give the best results) and download an updated `apt` .deb and install it with `dpkg`, since it appears your `apt` may be unable to do so itself.

Or, if you've recently udpated `apt`, then downgrading it to the previous version that was working yesterday or last week might work too.

Comment: I normally check for updates and install them at least every week and I had `ftp.de.debian.org` before and then changed to `ftp.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de`, but it didn't help.

Comment: The linked bug report indicates the error can happen with several servers, trying a few different ones around the world might help. Or deleting any partial files?

Comment: Thanks, the apt package from Debian Jessie works, I've upgraded it now

Comment: @msrd0 That's good news, if any answers were helpful you could upvote some, select/check-mark one that worked

Comment: That's not really new to me, I know how StackExchange works. But I solved the problem by upgrading apt and I need to wait 2 days until I can accept my own answer; and no other answer provided a way how I could resolve it

Comment: So, the idea to update apt was here, but not exactly what to type to do it? Sounds like most of an answer, imo...

Comment: APT in Debian wheezy can of course deal with a compressed `Packages` file. Debian wouldn't be distributing wheezy in a way that the wheezy package manager can't handle!

Comment: Ok you got upvote now, but I just checked by downgrading apt again, I had the newest available version of apt and it doesn't work again until upgrade to jessie

Comment: Thanks msrd0. From the different distro's bug reports something has definitely been going wrong with apt and at least some mirrors, it's not clear exactly what though